# XSLT Expertise required duplicate values

Tags: xslt

Question edited, more information added

viv:tokenize=str:tokenize

viv:value-of=str:value-of

Part1 - Declaration and assigning value

```
<declare name="searchhistories" />
<set-var name="searchhistories">
    <value-of select="concat(viv:value-of('searchquery','var'),'|',viv:replace(viv:value-of('searchhistory', 'var'),concat(viv:value-of('searchquery','var'),'\|'),'','g'))" />
  </set-var>
```

Part 2: tokenize and de-duplicate

```
      <xsl:for-each select="viv:tokenize($searchhistories,'|',false, false)">
      <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:if test="$i &lt; 11">      
      <xsl:value-of select="." /> |
      </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Able to tokenize but de-duplication not working

What should be code for de-duplication

```
      <xsl:for-each select=***distinct-values***("viv:tokenize($searchhistories,'|',false, false)")>
```

Something like this ?

Comment: Provide an example that shows simple stylesheet, simple input document, what outout you're getting and what you want to get.

Comment: "*should i use the distinct-values ?*" Yes, if your processor supports it. The context of your question is not clear: XSLT has no `viv:tokenize()` function.

Comment: It may be helpful if you can tell what processor you are using.  As @michael.hor257k said, there is no such function, and you seem to be using a processor extension function.  It may also be helpful if you can specify what version of the XSLT spec you are working with.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen. Anything with viv: is an extension of the standard xslt and exslt extensions. it uses the xslt engine under the hood. my input is like this ( abc|def|ijk ), and i use the tokenize function to split this into individual keywords. My final aim is to have only a single occurrence of a keyword.

Comment: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8NLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.dataexpl.engine.man.doc/r_viv_tokenize.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(viv:tokenize($searchhistories,'|',false, false))">
```

with the stylesheet declaring `xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" exclude-result-prefixes="set">
```

The answer is based on the documentation you linked to in your comment, I am not able to test that.

But http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcy uses the EXSLT version of tokenize and works fine:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(str:tokenize(., '|'))">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1">|</xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```